# Get contact Number as it is from Contact list

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-contacts, android-cursor, android-contentresolver

I ran into the problem while fetching contact using `ContentResolver`.

Contact list shows contact with spaces, but after fetching contact using content resolver it removing all spaces.

> Contact list : +91 XXXXX XXXXX
>
> After fetch : +91XXXXXXXXXX **(Wrong removing spaces)**

However it's not removing character if number is

> Contact list : +1 (XXX) XXX-XXXX
>
> After fetch : +1 (XXX) XXX-XXXX **(Correct as it is)**

**Below code is used to fetch contact**

```
 String order = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC";
 String[] projection = new String[]{ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME};
 Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, projection,
                null, null, order);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER` field can contain a number in any format, not necessarily a user displayable friendly one.
To format the number for display to the user, you can use the libphonenumber package by Google, which parses a phone number and allows you to format it into either a user friendly format, or the canonical e164 format useful for storing and comparing.

https://github.com/googlei18n/libphonenumber